# How do I load font-awesome using SCSS (SASS) in Webpack using relative paths?

Tags: node.js, sass, npm, font-awesome, webpack

I have font-awesome in my node_modules folder so I try to import it in my main .scss file like so:

```
@import "../../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss";
```

But Webpack bundling compilation fails, telling me

```
Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot
```

because the font-awesome.scss file refers to a relative path, '../fonts/'.

How can I tell scss \ webpack to @import another file, and use that file's folder as the home folder so that its relative paths work as it expects?

Comment: I don't knows webpack, but do you can put the .eot in `../../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot`?

Comment: I could do that by altering the font-awesome file, but then I'd lose the changes whenever I update npm, so that's not an option.

Comment: webpack works together express @Richard?

Comment: No, not using express

Comment: I am using the npm for font-awesome sass loader.  did you use a different one?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be any way to @import files that have their own relative paths in SCSS \ SASS.

So instead I managed to get [this](https://gist.github.com/Turbo87/e8e941e68308d3b40ef6) to work:

- Import the scss \ css font-awesome file in my .js or .jsx files, **not** my stylesheet files:

  ```
  import 'font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss';
  ```
- Add this to my webpack.config file:

```
    module:
    {
        loaders:
        [
            {test: /\.js?$/, loader: 'babel-loader?cacheDirectory', exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/ },
            {test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: 'babel-loader?cacheDirectory', exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/ },
            {test: /\.scss?$/, loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']},         
            {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader?mimetype=image/svg+xml'},
            {test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file-loader?mimetype=application/font-woff"},
            {test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file-loader?mimetype=application/font-woff"},
            {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file-loader?mimetype=application/octet-stream"},
            {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file-loader"},
        ]
    }
```

Comment: How do you handle a different font path? I mean you import the scss there but you cannot change the path to your font-files, e.g. if you need to change it for production and the fonts are found in a different folder. Any ideas? Thats what I need to do.

Comment: I haven't got to altering stuff for production yet. I imagine I'd just copy everything over from my local build and leave the paths alone.  Otherwise maybe look at the **output** section of **webpack.config.js** and see if you can change paths. Or just add a post build step in your **package.json** scripts section.

Comment: Got it working. I changed the path for the loader and now its loading the fonts from the specified path.

Comment: You don't need to include the font-awesome scss file in the javascript. You can still include it in your scss, as long as you set the font path like user137794 suggests, then update the webpack.config file to account for font types as you suggest.

Comment: Which npm did you use?  I am using the sass font awesome loader and having no success.

Comment: don't forget to add *-loader suffix (the loaders for .scss files). Leaving it without -loader suffix is not longer allowed. Check https://webpack.js.org/migrate/3/#automatic-loader-module-name-extension-removed

Answer (score 143):

Use

```
$fa-font-path: "~font-awesome/fonts";
@import "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";
```

where the `$fa-font-path` variable is seen in `font-awesome/scss/_variables.scss`

```
$fa-font-path: "../fonts" !default;
```

The tilde "~" is interpolated by sass-loader using [the webpack mecanism](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#resolving-import-at-rules).

Comment: Doesn't work for me, it compile but I just get rectangle in my website... :/

Comment: I had to set mine as `$fa-font-path: "font-awesome/fonts"` - i.e. without the tilde.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more precisely where you edit what? I don't understand this answer

Comment: @Richard were you able to get this working for you? Also, please mark this as the answer!

Comment: No, I used my answer below at the time.

Comment: The ~ was the secret sauce as my modules were in node_modules and the sass-loader was configured for them via include paths i.e., 
```JSON options: { sassOptions: { includePaths: [ "node_modules" ] }
```

Comment: @RobbVandaveer Could you please precisely where do I need to add this? Do I need to add this to webpack.config.js in root? Any reference link?

Comment: Hi @Sadee, I'm sorry for the late response, I guess I haven't been on SO in a while. The tilde prefixes the paths used as references in your SCSS.

Comment: This worked, but for parcel I had to use `$fa-font-path: '../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts';`

Answer (score 22):

Following worked for me:

```
$fa-font-path: "~font-awesome/fonts";
@import "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";
```

This is to import the `font-awesome` & required fonts in the project.
Other change is in `webpack` configurations, to load required fonts using `file-loader`.

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap', 'sass'
  ],
}, {
  test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)(\?.*$|$)/,
  loader: 'file'
}
```

Answer (score 22):

This is how it worked for me, the trick is to set `$fa-font-path` to the path of the fonts as following.

```
$fa-font-path: "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/";
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands.scss';
```

**Note**: Please check your fonts folder in `node_modules` in my case it is `@fortawesome/fontawesome-free`

Comment: @Muhammed Actually, it is a bit tricky to load webfonts like this. When you compile sass to css, according to your way of compiling, your fonts may not be compiled. You can copy the webfonts folder directly to your public/ folder next to your css folder. In this way, font awesome css code will find the fonts and you will be on the safe side.

Comment: This is what I thought I was doing. but what it turned out I was missing was the trailing directory separator at the end. (I had `$fa...: "~@fort..../webfonts";` when apparently it is fully required to have a trailing forward slash: `$fa...: "~@fort..../webfonts/";`) couldn't figure out why my otherwise working conifg was missing fonts from font awesome until I saw your answer here @Muhammad

Answer (score 13):

Resolved by changing my `app.scss`:

```
@import '~font-awesome/scss/_variables.scss';
$fa-font-path: "~font-awesome/fonts";
@import '~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss';
```

This way is useful to keep external dependencies unchanged and unversioned.

Comment: You could avoid line 1 and use ` !default` on line 2 end.

Comment: It's a shame that I can't get this method to work because it would mean that I didn't have to change the `_variables.scss` file every time I recompiled the project. It doesn't override `$fa-font-path` or any other variable for that matter.. so not sure how you were able to do it_

Answer (score 8):

I just set the path in my main scss file and it works :

```
$fa-font-path: "../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts";
@import '~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss';
```

Answer (score 7):

What worked for me was to add `resolve-url-loader` and enable `sourceMaps`

I already imported font-awesome in my root `.scss` file:

```
@import "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";
...
```

This root file is imported in my `main.js` file defined as Webpack's entrypoint:

```
import './scss/main.scss';
...
```

Then my final webpack module rules look like so:

```
 ...
 {
    test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
    use: [
      MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
      'css-loader',
      { loader: 'postcss-loader', options: { sourceMap: true }, },
      'resolve-url-loader',
      { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: true }, },
    ],
  }, {
    test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: { limit: 1000, name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]', },
  }
  ...
```

**Note:**

I used `mini-css-extract-plugin`, which can be registered like this:

```
new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: 'css/main.css',
    chunkFilename: '[id].[hash]',
}),
```

---

`url-loader` requires `file-loader` to be installed, so if you get an error like: `cannot find module file-loader`, then just install it:

```
npm i -D file-loader
```

---

*Useful Links*:

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2771#issuecomment-277514138
https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/384#issuecomment-301318904

Answer (score 4):

For Version 5.14, the following worked for me:

```
$fa-font-path : '../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts';

@import "../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid";

@import "../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands";

@import "../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome";
```

Answer (score 1):

Even after reading all answers, I did not copy anything but just read and still not working until i realized the scope name is `@fortawesome` and not `@fontawesome`.

So it will be

```
// to configure font path is necessary before importing scss
 $fa-font-path: '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/';

 @import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome";

//and so on .. for other scss
```

Answer (score 0):

v.4 (symofony 4 + webpack)

```
$fa-font-path: "~components-font-awesome/webfonts";
@import '~components-font-awesome/scss/fa-brands';
@import '~components-font-awesome/scss/fa-regular';
@import '~components-font-awesome/scss/fa-solid';
@import '~components-font-awesome/scss/fontawesome';
```