# Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' (import sass in webpack)

Tags: css, import, sass, webpack, webpack-dev-server

My project structure is:
[image]

/src/styles/main.scss

```
@import 'materialize/sass/materialize.scss';

....
```

I also try `@import './materialize/sass/materialize.scss';` here
notwork.

It only work when I import the lib in index.js

/src/index.js (this worked)

```
import './styles/reset.css';
import './styles/main.scss';
import './styles/font-awesome/font-awesome.scss';
```

webpack loader:

```
loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.js?/,
    exclude: [/node_modules/, /styles/],
    loaders: ['babel'],
    include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
  },
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loader: 'style!css!sass'
  },
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
  },
  {
    test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
    loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'
  },
  {
    test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
    loader: 'file-loader'
  }
```

]

But got error:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Thin.eot in E:\Project\simple-redux
-boilerplate\src\styles
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss 6:73945-73987 6:74010-74052

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Thin.woff2 in E:\Project\simple-red
ux-boilerplate\src\styles
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss 6:74104-74148

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Thin.woff in E:\Project\simple-redu
x-boilerplate\src\styles
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss 6:74181-74224

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Thin.ttf in E:\Project\simple-redux
-boilerplate\src\styles
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss 6:74256-74298

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Light.eot in E:\Project\simple-redu
x-boilerplate\src\styles
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss 6:74430-74473 6:74496-74539

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Light.woff2 in E:\Project\simple-re
dux-boilerplate\src\styles
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss 6:74591-74636

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Light.woff in E:\Project\simple-red
ux-boilerplate\src\styles
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss 6:74669-74713

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Light.ttf in E:\Project\simple-redu
x-boilerplate\src\styles
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss 6:74745-74788

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Regular.eot in E:\Project\simple-re
dux-boilerplate\src\styles
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss 6:74922-74967 6:74990-75035

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Regular.woff2 in E:\Project\simple-
redux-boilerplate\src\styles
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss 6:75087-75134

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Regular.woff in E:\Project\simple-r
edux-boilerplate\src\styles
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss 6:75167-75213

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf in E:\Project\simple-re
dux-boilerplate\src\styles
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss 6:75245-75290

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Medium.eot in E:\Project\simple-red
ux-boilerplate\src\styles
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss 6:75401-75445 6:75468-75512

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Medium.woff2 in E:\Project\simple-r
edux-boilerplate\src\styles
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss 6:75564-75610

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Medium.woff in E:\Project\simple-re
dux-boilerplate\src\styles
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss 6:75643-75688

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Medium.ttf in E:\Project\simple-red
ux-boilerplate\src\styles
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss 6:75720-75764

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Bold.eot in E:\Project\simple-redux
-boilerplate\src\styles
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss 6:75875-75917 6:75940-75982

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Bold.woff2 in E:\Project\simple-red
ux-boilerplate\src\styles
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss 6:76034-76078

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Bold.woff in E:\Project\simple-redu
x-boilerplate\src\styles
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss 6:76111-76154

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Bold.ttf in E:\Project\simple-redux
-boilerplate\src\styles
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss 6:76186-76228
```

It looks like `webpack` search for a wrong directory, not search `fonts` folder under `materialize`.

I got error every time when I put import sass lib in `main.scss`, which force me to put `import` to `index.js`. Anyway to workaround ?

**Update:**

I found there are config in 
`\src\styles\materialize\sass\components\_variables.scss`:

```
$roboto-font-path: "../fonts/roboto/" !default;
```

But it is relate to `components`, is this webpack 's bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is a problem related to `css-loader` or `sass-loader`, somehow they are not really resolving the paths correctly when inside `node_modules`. And that is the reason why you have those errors.

Look at the error:

```
Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Bold.woff in E:\Project\simple-redux-boilerplate\src\styles
```

It seems that the `css-loader` is trying to find `../fonts/` inside your `src/styles` folder.

As a **workaround**, you can specify the "correct" place where the fonts are placed as your `$roboto-font-path` variable. If installed via `npm install materialize-css` you can do the following:

```
$roboto-font-path: '~materialize-css/fonts/roboto/';
```

The tilde (~) character will say to your loaders to look into `node_modules`. Then, when resolving your paths, your loaders will look to the correct place and there will be no errors.

> I think (and tested it locally) you don't need to use the tilde character to look at `node_modules`using `sass-loader`.

If you **don't** want to look into `node_modules` (because you prefer to download the dependencies manually) you can just use the relative paths. In your case `$roboto-font-path: './materialize/fonts/roboto/';` should fix it.

---

**Update:**

You can also try using [`resolve-url-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/resolve-url-loader), that tries to fix the urls for you.

---

Related:

[How do I load font-awesome using SCSS (SASS) in Webpack using relative paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33649761/how-do-i-load-font-awesome-using-scss-sass-in-webpack-using-relative-paths)

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer! `resolve-url-loader` is really useful !

Comment: This method actually works for many of these similar `scss` dependency issues!