# Cannot import 'font-awesome/scss/variables' in local SCSS module

Tags: css, sass, font-awesome

I have Font Awesome v4.7.0 installed and I'm trying to write Sass classes that extend Font Awesome icon classes, like this:

```css
div.edit-icon {
  @extend .fa-pencil-square-o;
  font-size: $icon-font-size;
}
```

At the start of one of my SCSS files (`_shared.scss`), I try importing the bare essentials I need from Font Awesome (installed in `node_modules`):

```css
@import '~font-awesome/scss/variables';
@import '~font-awesome/scss/mixins';
@import '~font-awesome/scss/icons';
```

However, Webpack gives me this error when I save the file:

```
ERROR in ./~/sass-extract-loader!./app/views/components/_shared.scss
Module build failed: Error: File to import not found or unreadable: ~font-awesome/scss/variables.
Parent style sheet: C:/Users/<me>/WebstormProjects/<project>/app/views/components/_shared.scss
    at options.error (C:\Users\<me>\WebstormProjects\<project>\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:291:26)
 @ ./app/views/components/candb/MessageDefinitionView/CoreMessageDefinitionView.tsx 9:28-77
 @ ./app/views/components/candb/MessageDefinitionView/TxMessageDefinitionView.tsx
 @ ./app/views/components/candb/index.ts
 @ ./app/views/components/index.ts
 @ ./app/views/layouts/Page/Page.tsx
 @ ./app/routes.tsx
 @ ./app/index.tsx
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:1212 webpack/hot/dev-server react-hot-loader/patch webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:1212/ webpack/hot/only-dev-server ./app/index.tsx
```

Here's the start of `node_modules\font-awesome\scss\_variables.scss`:

```css
// Variables
// --------------------------

$fa-font-path:        "../fonts" !default;
$fa-font-size-base:   14px !default;
$fa-line-height-base: 1 !default;
//$fa-font-path:        "//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/fonts" !default; // for referencing Bootstrap CDN font files directly
$fa-css-prefix:       fa !default;
$fa-version:          "4.7.0" !default;
$fa-border-color:     #eee !default;
$fa-inverse:          #fff !default;
$fa-li-width:         (30em / 14) !default;
```

What I noticed is that the value of `$fa-css-prefix` is an unquoted string (fa), and that commenting out this assignment allows this SCSS file to compile.

How is it legal for this string to be unquoted, and what can I do to allow me to import this SCSS file?

For reference, this is a relevant part of my Webpack config for loading SCSS modules:

```js
// Add SASS support  - compile all other .scss files and pipe it to style.css
{
  test: /^((?!\.global).)*\.scss$/,
  loader: extractModuleCSS.extract({
    fallback: 'style-loader',
    use: [
    'css-loader?modules&sourceMap&camelCase&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
    'sass-loader'
    ]
  })
}
```

---

**Edit**

I thought that the fact that Webpack displayed an error about a different file when I commented out `$fa-css-prefix: ...` meant that at least `_variables.scss` was compiling fine:

```
Undefined variable: "$fa-css-prefix".
          in C:\Users\<me>\WebstormProjects\<project>\node_modules\font-awesome\scss\_icons.scss (line 4, column 4)
```

Apparently that isn't the case, though. If I comment out the other imports in `_shared` like this:

```css
@import '~font-awesome/scss/variables';
//@import '~font-awesome/scss/mixins';
//@import '~font-awesome/scss/icons';
```

Then I still see the original error ('File to import not found or unreadable: ~font-awesome/scss/variables.') *regardless of the changes I make to `_variables.scss`* - even commenting out the entire file.

I've updated the title to reflect this new information.

**Edit 2**

Based on @CloudTseng's advice I tried this:

```css
$fa-css-prefix: 'fa';
@import '~font-awesome/scss/variables';
@import '~font-awesome/scss/core';
@import '~font-awesome/scss/icons';

$icon-font-size: 16px;

div.edit-icon {
  @extend .fa;
  @extend .fa-pencil-square-o;
  font-size: $icon-font-size;
}

div.cross-icon {
  @extend .fa;
  @extend .fa-times;
  font-size: $icon-font-size;
}
```

Surprisingly, this gives me exactly what I want. The reason I find this surprising is that apparently I only needed to redefine `fa-css-prefix` locally - I was expecting that I would have to redefine *all* the Font Awesome variables from `_variables.scss` if I went this route.

However, inspecting my generated CSS shows me that all the other variables are magically resolved without me needing to redefine them:

*font-awesome/scss/_icons.scss*:

```css
.#{$fa-css-prefix}-glass:before { content: $fa-var-glass; }
.#{$fa-css-prefix}-music:before { content: $fa-var-music; }
.#{$fa-css-prefix}-search:before { content: $fa-var-search; }
...
```

*/dist/modules.css*:

```css
/* Font Awesome uses the Unicode Private Use Area (PUA) to ensure screen
   readers do not read off random characters that represent icons */
.app-views-components-candb-FieldDefinitionTable-___FieldDefinitionTable__fa-glass___2rm6a:before {
  content: "\F000"; }

.app-views-components-candb-FieldDefinitionTable-___FieldDefinitionTable__fa-music___3q-Vg:before {
  content: "\F001"; }

.app-views-components-candb-FieldDefinitionTable-___FieldDefinitionTable__fa-search___f89bE:before {
  content: "\F002"; }
...
```

Comment: I suggest you read this [page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33649761/how-do-i-load-font-awesome-using-scss-sass-in-webpack-using-relative-paths). it will help me.

Comment: @CloudTseng Thanks, that helped! If you'd like, you can submit an answer. I'd appreciate if you'd explain why I only needed to redefine `fa-css-prefix` and not every other variable (as I was worried I would have to).